# What is the probability that more than two of the same titles are found on all three lists?

Tags: probability

**Girl's Night**

Audrey, Brooke and Caroline are planning a long movie night. They want to binge-watch some films together from their favorite director. But they can't decide on the selection of movies, because they have a deal that they must all agree on the films they watch. Moreover, their preferences are very different, and there are eleven titles to choose from. After long discussions, Caroline proposes the following: "Each one of us independently writes a list of **five** of the **eleven** titles. The order is not important." Audrey is enthusiastic about the idea. Brooke, on the other hand, is skeptical, saying, "*I don't think we can agree on more than two titles using this procedure.*"

**What is the probability that more than two of the same titles are found on all three lists?**

(This is not a textbook / homework question. I solved the problem with a computer. Now I wonder, is this problem analytically solvable.)

Comment: Welcome to cv, Julia! Users of this site love to help with textbook / homework questions, but are ambitious and want the original poster help to understand :-) and not just give the solution. If you agree, please indicate in your question where you are stuck, and consider adding the self-study tag.

Comment: Thank you, Ute. This is not a textbook / homework question. I solved the problem with a computer. Now I wonder, is this problem analytically solvable.

Comment: Super! You could adf your comment to the qiestion, and if this is a short program in a common language, you could add it as well :-). If the program is not brite force, an analytical answer can follow its lines.

Comment: The program is very simple, but brute force. I don't think you can solve the problem without a computer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot solve this question without an assumption about the probability that A, B or C set title T on their list. As the problem is posed, I assume that each girl randomly sets $k=5$ crosses on her list of $n=11$ titles, with each title having the same probability of being chosen.

It is probably easiest to calculate the probability of exactly $m$ same titles on lists A,B, C, and add up the probabilities for $m=3, 4$ and $5$.

To calculate the probability for $m$ same titles, we need to define a system of equally likely outcomes for all three lists, and then divide the number of "successes" by the number of all possible outcomes. Here we can take a shortcut: say, A makes her list first. For each possible lists A, the probability that $m$ of the titles chosen by A also occur on B and C is the same. Therefore we can take the choices made by A as given, and continue from there. Now there are $k$ titles that A has chosen, and $n-k$ other titles.

The number of possible lists made by B and C is equal to $\binom{n}{k}\cdot\binom{n}{k}$. To get the number of successes, let $\ell$ denote the number of crosses that B choses from the $k$ titles that were already chosen by A. In order to allow for $m$ titles chosen by all three girls, we need that $\ell \geq m$. The number of possible choices ($k$ titles) for $B$ that contain exactly $\ell$ from the A-titles is $\binom{k}{\ell}\cdot\binom{n-k}{k-\ell}$. Then C has to choose $m$ from the $\ell$ titles and $k-m$ from the remaining titles in order to have $m$ that have been chosen by both A and B before. In all, C has $\binom{\ell}{m}\cdot\binom{n-\ell}{k-m}$ options. Summing up over all possible $\ell$, we find that the probability $p(m;n,k)$ for exactly $m$ same titles is
$$p(m;n,k) = \frac{\sum_{\ell=m}^k \binom{k}{\ell}\binom{n-k}{k-\ell}\cdot\binom{\ell}{m}\binom{n-\ell}{k-m}}{\binom{n}{k}^2}, \quad m\leq k.$$
With the concrete values $n=11$, $k=5$, we get
$$
P(\text{at least three same titles})=p(3;11,5)+p(4;11,5)+p(5;11,5)=\frac{6870+240+1}{462^2}\approx 0.033316.
$$

In the eyes of a classically trained statistician, this is a small chance (< 5%). Therefore, we might suspect that Brooke is a statistician ;-)

Comment: Thank you so much, Ute.

Comment: That's a cool idea, keeping A's choice fixed, as it doesn't matter which of the films are chosen, it matters that these are *her* five.